# Do we normally "itch" or "rub" while feeling itch in the back?

Tags: word-choice

Sometimes it happens to be that people feel some itch in the back. They may ask their friend / spouse **to itch or to rub** the place where they feel itch. What is normally this action called in English, *to itch*, *to rub* or maybe something else?

I've checked both definitions in [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/itch?q=ITCH) and it confuses me a little bit, because the definition by itself makes these two words allegedly like synonyms for this context. Isn't it?

> **Itch** (v): to have or cause an uncomfortable feeling on the skin that makes you want **to rub** it with your nails:

Comment: "To scratch".  You *scratch* an itch.

Comment: I found this source as useful as well:  https://www.dictionary.com/e/itch-vs-scratch/

Answer (score 4):

The use of the word Itch in this context is nonstandard English. Although it's common to hear people say this, the best word to use is scratch.

> I have an itch on my back, could you please **scratch** it for me?

Rub works as well, though I don't think of "rubbing" as curing an itch, as much as I think of scratching.

Comment: Thank you for your answer 1+^. I also learnt from your answer that I should say "**on** the back" rather than "**in** the back" as in my question. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes "**on** the back" would be proper.

Comment: By the way why did you use an article "an" while referring to "itch"? Is it countable noun?

Comment: @Incompatible_alterations Yes, it's countable.

Comment: BTW, "an itch **in** my back" is also correct. Lots of results in books, e. g. [1](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=0t0pywRquQkC&pg=PT20&lpg=PT20&dq=%22an+itch+in+my+back%22&source=bl&ots=a9SvtF5Bj8&sig=LBrqGFsjT2POyBY-8D1C9rh5BA8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr49Ds6LfZAhUBh6YKHddqA0AQ6AEILTAC#v=onepage&q=%22an%20itch%20in%20my%20back%22), [2](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=ZnZ59RwsYVsC&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=%22an+itch+in+my+back%22&source=bl&ots=z32dJ-1XQ9&sig=WaKBFkNMDX56jdiat1rJoFJSbQs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr49Ds6LfZAhUBh6YKHddqA0AQ6AEIMzAE#v=onepage&q=%22an%20itch%20in%20my%20back%22)

Answer (score 1):

The verb "itch", as the dictionary tells you, is always about something that gives you an uncomfortable feeling. It can**not** be used to describe the action of alleviating this feeling.

It's either a part of your body that has an itch /itches (in this case, the verb "itch" is used intransitively). E.g.,

> My neck itches.

Or it's some object that gives you  or a part of your body that feeling (in this case, the verb "itch" is used transitively). E.g.,

> that suit itched him ([source](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=zcguFoAKVzEC&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=%22itched+him%22&source=bl&ots=jYk37m9FHw&sig=oNScIZSAoxpr5JMQNPpQ8isi4Wo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK56re5LfZAhWHVywKHT64Ae8Q6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22itched%20him%22&f=false))

(meaning the suit was made from a fabric that caused a feeling of itchiness)

The action to alleviate this feeling of itchiness is usually "**scratching** that itch".

Searching for "scratching that itch" on Google (in quotation marks) produces about 237,000 results.

This phrase can also be used metaphorically. When someone is "itching to do something", it means they want badly to do this thing. So, for example, if someone was itching to paint, one could enroll in an art class *to scratch that itch*.

> Someone has an itch to scratch...

... is an idiom that means that someone wants to do something, so bad that s/he can't overcome this urge. E. g., in [this article](https://www.postguam.com/sports/local/okuhama-to-continue-tennis-journey-at-whittier/article_b2c3ca3c-894c-11e7-9b4f-f7b0fd284750.html), the journalist tells us that every athlete, sooner or later, must leave the sports (because of age or whatever), but this particular athlete, to whom the article is devoted, "still has an itch to scratch"—so he continues competing.